# How to Use ON DUPLICATE KEY Inside wpdb Query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a INSERT query that submits a new row into my database table. But I also want to be able to update the row with a new meta_value if a row with a matching company_id and meta_key exist. Is this possible to do with ON DUPLICATE KEY inside my query if so how? And if not what are my alternatives?

My current query:

```
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}pending_company_meta (company_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $companyId, $key, $value)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}pending_company_meta (company_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = VALUES(meta_value)
```

For this to work, you need a primary key (or unique key) constraint on `(company_id, meta_key)`.